# Negative lognormal results in Monte Carlo simulation with Brightway2

Tags: python, brightway

I can't figure out how to set up BW2 to get negative values in a MC simulation for a parameter with lognormal distribution, e.g. to model negative emissions. Example:

```
from brightway2 import *
import numpy as np


mydb = Database('mydb')

mydb.write({
    ('mydb', 'Some activity'): {
        'name': 'Some activity',
        'unit': 'kWh',
        'exchanges': [{
            'input': ('mydb', 'Carbon dioxide'),
            'amount': 20, # positive!
            'unit': 'kg',
            'type': 'biosphere', 
            'uncertainty type' : 2,
            'loc' : np.log(20), 
            'scale' : 1.01 
            }]
    },
    ('mydb', 'Carbon dioxide'): {'name': 'Carbon dioxide', 'unit': 'kg', 'type': 'biosphere'}
    })

exc = list(mydb.get('Some activity').exchanges())[0]
exc.as_dict()
exc.random_sample(n=10)
```

This works. I get:

```
Out[8]: 
array([ 25.20415107,  17.48476344,  16.98842921,   3.79548038,
    12.54165042,  27.93752377,   7.57070571,  43.22285015,
    48.44984804,  13.83083672]) # everything fine
```

Now let's assume I want to get the same values but negative: `array([ -25.20415107,  -17.48476344, etc. ...` because I assume I have a carbon uptake of -20 kg Carbon dioxide. If I write `'amount': -20` I get a weird result:

```
Out[9]: 
array([   0.73060359,   36.69825867,    5.71416558,   10.78119397,
     16.24447705,    2.96507057,    6.73564118,   19.24411117,
      7.23110067,  126.42690714])
```

I know lognormal distributions can't be negative, but what I was expecting is that the distribution was calculated on positive values based on the 'loc' and 'scale' information and then reversed based on the 'amount' information. This is necessary to perform MC on an inventory with negative emissions. Any clue? Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There were two problems preventing expected behaviour:

1. It isn't enough to give a negative value in the field `amount`; the RNG code is in the [stats_arrays](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/stats_arrays) library, and you must set the field `negative` to `True` ([see docs](https://stats-arrays.readthedocs.io/en/latest/#parameter-array)).
2. There was a bug in `brightway2-data`, fixed in [7e3341c](https://bitbucket.org/cmutel/brightway2-data/commits/7e3341cb8c33bc13b4d8bcea1bc0f66333dbe68a) and release [2.4.6](http://anaconda%20upload%20/Users/cmutel/miniconda3/conda-bld/noarch/bw2data-2.4.6-py_0.tar.bz2%20), that prevented the key `negative` from being used in `exchange.uncertainty`.

In general, when importing data from other formats the `negative` field is set automatically, e.g. [SimaPro CSV](https://bitbucket.org/cmutel/brightway2-io/src/3390d0f3155133cd05a3e5eed904f36356ede6e1/bw2io/extractors/simapro_csv.py?at=default&fileviewer=file-view-default#simapro_csv.py-244), [Ecospold 1](https://bitbucket.org/cmutel/brightway2-io/src/3390d0f3155133cd05a3e5eed904f36356ede6e1/bw2io/extractors/ecospold1.py?at=default&fileviewer=file-view-default#ecospold1.py-293). Moreover, when a database is processed to a parameter array, the `negative` field is also [always set](https://bitbucket.org/cmutel/brightway2-data/src/a63b43805a46eb135315ef03babbac618f1aa296/bw2data/backends/peewee/database.py?at=default&fileviewer=file-view-default#database.py-428) from the `amount field`. The difference in this case is that you are calling functions from `stats_arrays` directly, instead of through `brightway2-calc`.

Adding the `negative` field on an up-to-date installation:

```
from brightway2 import *
import numpy as np
projects.set_current("SO 45935773")
bw2setup()

mydb = Database('mydb')
gwp = ('IPCC 2013', 'climate change', 'GWP 100a')
co2 = get_activity(('biosphere3', '349b29d1-3e58-4c66-98b9-9d1a076efd2e'))

mydb.write({
    ('mydb', 'Some activity'): {
        'name': 'Some activity',
        'unit': 'kWh',
        'exchanges': [{
            'input': co2.key,
            'amount': -20, # negative
            'negative': True,
            'unit': 'kg',
            'type': 'biosphere', 
            'uncertainty type' : 2,
            'loc' : np.log(20), 
            'scale' : 1.01 
        }]
    }
})

exc = list(mydb.get('Some activity').exchanges())[0]
exc.random_sample(n=10)
```

Produces the expected behaviour:

```
array([ -3.24683872,  -5.01873359, -31.54532003, -40.59523805,
       -54.00447092,  -6.11459063, -41.5250442 ,  -8.05295075,
       -31.46077832, -29.8769442 ])
```

Comment: Excellent, thanks for your help and info. I was actually fighting with the 'negative' option just before your answer arrived. I tested your code with the brightway version I had and as you expected it didn't work. Then I updated brightway and the code worked and behaved as expected (I get the negative results). I confirm on a more complex case with LCIA method, file imported from Simapro CSV, etc. etc. things were fine even without manually specifying 'negative' to be true. Thanks.